# PHP mysql query result into multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
while ($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {    
$basicinfo[] = array('schlid' => $selected_row['schlid'], 'name' => $selected_row['name'], 'class' => $selected_row['class']);
}
```

The above making of array will result into a array that has multiple value the array will look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [schlid] => 015-08-0011-000-01
            [name] => John
            [class] => Math 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [schlid] => 015-08-0011-000-01
            [name] => John
            [class] => English 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [schlid] => 015-08-0011-000-01
            [name] => John
            [class] => Math 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [schlid] => 015-08-0011-000-01
            [name] => John
            [class] => English 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [schlid] => 015-08-0011-000-01
            [name] => John
            [class] => Math 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [schlid] => 015-08-0011-000-01
            [name] => John
            [class] => English 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [schlid] => 015-08-0011-000-01
            [name] => John
            [class] => Math 
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [schlid] => 015-08-0011-000-01
            [name] => John
            [class] => English 
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [schlid] => 015-08-0011-000-01
            [name] => John
            [class] => Math 
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [schlid] => 015-08-0011-000-01
            [name] => John
            [class] => English 
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [schlid] => 015-08-0011-000-01
            [name] => John
            [class] => Math 
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [schlid] => 015-08-0011-000-01
            [name] => John
            [class] => English 
        )

)
```

But i am able to remove the same value just by doing this below

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $basicinfo)));
$new_data = array_values($input);
```

and i will get this below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [schlid] => 015-08-0011-000-01
            [name] => John
            [class] => Math 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [schlid] => 015-08-0011-000-01
            [name] => John
            [class] => English 
        )
)
```

Now what i did is to make a multidimensional array of the same query result as this

```
    while ($selected_row = $stmt - > fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         $tmp_key = $selected_row['schlid']; //adding a temp key
         $basicinfo[$tmp_key]['name'] = $selected_row['name'];
         $basicinfo[$tmp_key]['schlid'] = $selected_row['schlid'];
         $sudky = (isset($basicinfo[$tmp_key]['Class'])) ? count($basicinfo[$tmp_key]['Class']) : 0;
         $basicinfo[$tmp_key]['Class'][$sudky]['class'] = $selected_row['class'];
    }
```

From above the result i get is

```
Array
(
    [015-08-0011-000-01] => Array
        (
            [schlid] => 015-08-0011-000-01
            [name] => John
            [Class] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => Math 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => English 
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => Math 
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => English 
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => Math 
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => English 
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => Math 
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => English 
                        )

                    [8] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => Math 
                        )

                    [9] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => English 
                        )

                    [10] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => Math 
                        )

                    [11] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => English 
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

My desired out is

```
Array
(
    [015-08-0011-000-01] => Array
        (
            [schlid] => 015-08-0011-000-01
            [name] => John
            [Class] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => Math 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [class] => English 
                        )
                )

        )

)
```

To remove duplicate elements in a multidimensional aray.
The result above is from `print_r()` in php if this is relevant

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for` **loop** to check **before** you assigning the student class or deal with the array that contains repetitive classes **after output** using [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

```
$basicinfo[$tmp_key]['Class'][0] = array_unique($basicinfo[$tmp_key]['Class'][0]); //<-The array that you don't want duplicates in. i modify the formating
```

Comment: its worth a try let me try it

Comment: Try without `[0]` as well